# These BNF's codes are difficult for me to understand

Tags: computer-science, bnf, ebnf

I read a paper about BNF, and there are some codes I don't understand.

```
terminal ::=
    """value":"value"""
value ::=
    ["$"]letters_and_or_digits
```

I don't understand the `"""value":"value"""`means.

And the `letters_and_digits` has no more definition. Does this make it work? Or if I want to define the `letters_and_or_digits`. What should I do?

Thank you.

Comment: I assume that "value" in line 2 refers to the symbol on line 3, and possibly "" is a special sequence which means a literal quote ".

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that's from [1], where it is said to be in extended BNF, I'd translate it into BNF with literals and character classes as follows:

```
terminal ::= quote value quote
quote ::= '"' 

value ::= letters_and_or_digits
value ::= sigil letters_and_or_digits
sigil ::= '$' 
letters_and_or_digits ::= [a-zA-Z0-9]+
```

Note: `[]` in EBNF means an option, so `["$"]letters_and_or_digits` is
    interpreted as bare `letters_and_or_digits` or
    `letters_and_or_digits` preceded with `$`.

[1] "All grammar files are written using an extended 
Backus Naur Form (BNF) syntax" -- http://www.exida.com/images/uploads/On%20Shaky%20Ground%20-%20NPIC_HMIT_2006%20Paper.pdf